# Traverse through a DAG-like structure to produce another DAG-like structure in Clojure

Tags: clojure, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG-like structure that is essentially a deeply-nested `map`. The maps in this structure can have common values, so the overall structure is not a *tree* but a *direct acyclic graph*. I'll refer to this structure as a *DAG* for brevity.

The nodes in this graph are of different but finite number of categories. Each category can have its own structure/keywords/number-of-children. There is one unique node that is the source of this DAG, meaning from this node we can reach all nodes in the DAG.

The task is to traverse through the DAG from the source node, and convert each node to another one or more nodes in a new constructed graph. I'll give an example for illustration.

[image: Illustration of Graph Transformation]

The graph in the upper half is the input one. The lower half is the one after transformation. For simplicity, the transformation is only done on node A where it is split into node 1 and A1. The children of node A are also reallocated.

What I have tried (or in mind):

1. Write a function to convert one object for different types. Inside this function, recursively call itself to convert each of its children. This method suffers from the problem that data are immutable. The nodes in the transformed graph cannot be changed randomly to add children. To overcome this, I need to wrap every node in a ref/atom/agent.
2. Do a topological sort on the original graph. Then convert the nodes in the reversed order, i.e., bottom-up. This method requires a extra traverse of the graph but at least the data need not to be mutable. Regarding the topological sort algorithm, I'm considering DFS-based method as stated in the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) page, which does not require the knowledge of the full graph nor a node's parents.

My question is:

1. Is there any other approaches you might consider, possibly more elegant/efficient/idiomatic?
2. I'm more in favour of the second method, is there any flaws or potential problems?

Thanks!

EDIT: On a second thought, a topological sorting is not necessary. The transformation can be done in the post-order traversal already.

Comment: Having a dag case. Did walkers do the job here?

Comment: @FrançoisDeSerres Yes, that's the way I took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a perfect application of [Zippers](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.zip-api.html). They  have all the capabilities you described as needed and can produce the edited 'new' DAG. There are also a number of libraries that ease the search and replace capability using predicate threads.

I've used zippers when working with OWL ontologies defined in nested vector or map trees.

Another option would be to take a look at [Walkers](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html) although I've found these a bit more tedious to use.

Comment: Cool. I'll dig in *zipper* and see how. Thanks

Comment: Zippers are only usable for trees, while clojure.walker can walk on DAGs.

Comment: That is true and my fault for not asking how the edge relationships are managed.